# A default flag on a table in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a simple table/model in rails, `vat_rates`. Administrators need to be able to select one, and only one of these as the default rate that will be selected on the HTML form when creating new related items items that have a `vat_rate_id`. I have added a boolean `default` column to the `vat_rates` table.

What is the most straight forward, and rails-like way to ensure that only one `vat_rate` can be the default one at any time?

I'm not really bothered if there are no defaults, just that there are no more than one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a custom validation method like [this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#creating-custom-validation-methods) and return an error if another vat_rate is selected as default already.  Alternatively you can add a before_update or after_update callback like [this](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html) to set all other default values to false on update.

Comment: I'd like setting one record as the default to cause the old default to update rather than cause a validation error.